# Why does Fabric Composer npm-install fail for my Ubuntu setup?

Tags: npm-install, hyperledger-composer

I'm a newbie to npm and hyperledger fabric-composer
Question: What is the problem with my setup? What is the strategy to investigate and solve such errors?

What I did:

1. Setup Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS (64-bit)
2. Installing prerequisites using the script provided on
   https://fabric-composer.github.io/tasks/prerequisites.html

Executing npm install causes (don't know if this info is sufficient):

```
[...]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/transport/ssladapter.py", line 22, in <module>
    urllib3.connection.match_hostname = match_hostname
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connection'

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-31-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/mjh/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.2/bin/node" "/home/mjh/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.2/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.6.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! getting-started@1.0.0 install: `scripts/download-hyperledger.sh && scripts/start-hyperledger.sh && npm run deployNetwork`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the getting-started@1.0.0 install script 'scripts/download-hyperledger.sh && scripts/start-hyperledger.sh && npm run deployNetwork'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the getting-started package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     scripts/download-hyperledger.sh && scripts/start-hyperledger.sh && npm run deployNetwork
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs getting-started
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls getting-started
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/mjh/sample-applications/packages/getting-started/npm-debug.log
```

See link for detailed npm-debug.log file 
https://gist.github.com/mjh-halder/9fe473b44f0a731c996bbc5754011013

Comment: Looking at the log it seems that npm install has worked but there's a problem with the docket download.  Two things.. what version of python do you have (exact version) and I would try running the `scripts/download-hyperledger.sh` directly - issue npm run and you can see the script can be done separately.

Comment: In a different forum we've had reports of a similar installation error on Ubuntu 14.  The problem was some of the self-signed certificates within node-gyp.
 The solution was to set `export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` before doing the `npm install -g composer-cli`

Worth trying that I think. Please feedback on what happens!

Comment: @Calanais python version is 2.7.6 (python3 is 3.4.3); I set the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED variable and executed the npm install command you suggested - unfortunately same error appears.
I didn't get what you meant with "try running the .sh directly" Could you please be more specific what I'm supposed to do? As mentioned I'm new to npm...

Comment: After further investigation and reproducing the problem, it suggests that the problem is related to installation of docker-compose - please see my answer below and try that.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @neuromouse yes, the installation worked with an updated version of the scripts. However, I think the installation documentation was changed since then. I don't know if the current version works on my system...

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this problem before on trusty (14.04) and relates to an out of date urllib3 library for python, which is used by docker compose.
depending on which version of pip you have installed you can update the urllib library as follows

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install -U urllib3
```

Comment: Had the same problem as MJH. The problem was, pip was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing permissions, so you need to do `sudo npm-install ...`

Comment: Please **describe** your answer and not just using **code**. Otherwise may your answer will be deleted!

Comment: Do I really need to explain what `sudo` does? Wouldn't it be duplicating knowledge as there are about 24,100,000 results when Googling it? Go ahead and delete my answer. I'm trying to help, not to get points.

Comment: This is not my opinion. your posted is recommended for deleting. I just comment for your. Do not get mad

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is related to the last part of the installation script - this is the part that installs the `docker-compose` tool. Testing this today on a clean Ubuntu 14.04 LTS image, that was the cause.

I'd recommend installing `docker-compose` following the instructions on the docker site. (https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)

In effect this is

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o 
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Run the `docker-compose --version` to check it's installed correctly

```
$ docker-compose --version

docker-compose version: 1.10.0
```

Then run the rest of the Fabric Composer scripts as before.

We're updating the script - but this should get you going.

Comment: unfortunately same error appears. (I installed docker-compose, 'docker-compose --version' returns the same version)
I guess with "rest of the fabric composer scripts you mean the prerequisite scripts? I tried to run them several several times. However when I run npm install within the getting started package the error still appears.

Note: I also did this with a clean Ubuntu 14.04 image